# Editable Subgrid setting the required field from onchange event broken

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

We were using [this snippet](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/debajitcrm/posts/access-your-cell-values-easily-during-on-change-event-of-field-in-dynamics-crm-editable-sub-grid) on an editable subgrid in a form, while one of the attribute trigger `onchange` event triggering this function and the necessary fields were marked as required so far. So users cannot save the editable subgrid row and autosave will also get blocked with a notification message.

Suddenly it stopped working now and no errors or exceptions while debugging, though the field is marked as required from `onchange` function - still users are able to save the record without value in required field. No clue why this behavior change is observed now.

Anyone else faced this issue and any workaround for this?

```
function ReasonChange(eContext) {
    debugger;
    // get the attribute which fired the onchange.
    var reasonAttr = eContext.getEventSource();

    // get the container for the attribute.
    var attrParent = reasonAttr.getParent();

    // get the value of the reason.
    var reason = reasonAttr.getValue(); 

    if (reason != null) {

        // var field1 Attribute
        var field1 = attrParent.attributes.get("new_followupdate");

        //Callback
        if (reason[0].id == "{33E9E459-5A8B-EA11-A812-000D3A5A17E3}") {

            // set field as mandatory.
            field1.setRequiredLevel("required");
        }
        else {

            //clear field value
            field1.setValue(null);

            // set field as mandatory.
            field1.setRequiredLevel("none");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround i could think now is to add code on Onsave event and check if field value contains data if not show error message.

Also, have you checked in other browser if the behavior is same or different?

Please mark my answer verified if i were helpful

Comment: yeah thanks, same experience in Edge too. OnSave is little tricky to iterate all rows, do you having any working code sample. Tried using Business rule also, something strange is happening, but not sure why this is so complicated. Planning to move to plugin as a last resort, instead of wasting more time on this/